# Как сделать перенос строки в таблице?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.15

Когда создаю документ с использованием  QTextDocumentWriter в формате "odf", перенос строк в таблице  не работает. Когда создаю "html"  документ, перенос строк в таблице  работает. Необходим формат "odf" для более старых версий открытого офиса. В более старых версиях версия офиса "HTML"  не открывается.
Как сделать перенос строки таблице в "odf" формате?
Приложил тестовый код:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QTextDocumentWriter>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QTextBlock>
#include <QDate>
#include <QTextTableCell>

void createsOdfWithTable(){
QTextDocument *doc = new QTextDocument;
doc->setDocumentMargin(10);

QTextCursor cursor(doc);
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);

QTextCharFormat textFormat;
textFormat.setFontPointSize(10);
QTextCharFormat boldFormat;
boldFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);

//HEADERS
QTextCharFormat header1Format = boldFormat;
header1Format.setFontPointSize(12);
header1Format.setFontUnderline(true);
header1Format.setForeground(QBrush(QColor("#0000FF")));

QTextCharFormat header2Format = header1Format;
header2Format.setFontPointSize(14);
QTextCharFormat header3Format = header1Format;
header3Format.setFontPointSize(16);

QTextCharFormat titleFormat = boldFormat;
titleFormat.setFontPointSize(20);
header1Format.setForeground(QBrush(QColor("#0000FF")));

QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = cursor.block().blockFormat();
QTextBlockFormat titleBlockFormat = cursor.block().blockFormat();
titleBlockFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

QTextCharFormat alternateCellFormat = textFormat;
alternateCellFormat.setBackground(QBrush(QColor("#D1EBFF")));

QTextTableFormat tableFormat;
tableFormat.setBorder(1);
tableFormat.setBorderStyle(QTextFrameFormat::BorderStyle_Solid);
tableFormat.setCellPadding(2);
tableFormat.setCellSpacing(0);
tableFormat.setWidth(QTextLength(QTextLength::PercentageLength, 80));
tableFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);

//Title of the document
cursor.insertBlock();
cursor.setBlockCharFormat(titleFormat);
cursor.setBlockFormat(titleBlockFormat);
cursor.insertText(QObject::tr("My Great Document !"));
cursor.insertBlock(); //new line
cursor.insertBlock();
cursor.insertBlock();

cursor.setBlockFormat(blockFormat);
cursor.insertText(QObject::tr("Header 1"), header1Format);
cursor.insertBlock();

cursor.setCharFormat(textFormat);

cursor.insertText("Author:\tMe");
cursor.insertBlock();
cursor.insertText("Version:\tMe");
cursor.insertBlock();
cursor.insertText("Date:\t" + QDate::currentDate().toString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
cursor.insertBlock();

cursor.insertText(QObject::tr("Header 2"), header2Format);
cursor.insertBlock();
cursor.insertText(QObject::tr("Header 3"), header3Format);
cursor.insertBlock();

//Insert table with nb row = 10, column = 2
QTextTable *table = cursor.insertTable(10+1, 2, tableFormat);
QTextTableCell headerCell = table->cellAt(0, 0);
QTextCursor headerCellCursor = headerCell.firstCursorPosition();
headerCellCursor.insertText(QObject::tr("Name"), boldFormat);
headerCell = table->cellAt(0, 1);
headerCellCursor = headerCell.firstCursorPosition();
headerCellCursor.insertText(QObject::tr("Value"), boldFormat);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    QTextCharFormat cellFormat = i % 2 == 0 ? textFormat : alternateCellFormat;
    QTextTableCell cell = table->cellAt(i + 1, 0);
    cell.setFormat(cellFormat);
    QTextCursor cellCursor = cell.firstCursorPosition();
    cellCursor.insertText("Row \n" + QString::number(i));

    cell = table->cellAt(i + 1, 1);
    cell.setFormat(cellFormat);
    cellCursor = cell.firstCursorPosition();
    cellCursor.insertText(QString::number(i));
}

cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);


QTextDocumentWriter writer("test3.odt");
writer.setFormat("odf");
writer.write(doc);
QTextDocumentWriter writer2("test4.odt");
writer2.setFormat("html");
writer2.write(doc);

delete doc;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
createsOdfWithTable();
return a.exec();
}
```

[image: HTML]
[image: ODF]

Comment: Легче разрабам написать, чем тут спрашивать. Код открыт и там есть контакты разработчиков в репозе - пишите любому

Comment: А где контакты разработчиков указаны? Можно ссылку?

Comment: https://openoffice.apache.org/contact.html

Comment: А вы думаете это проблемы с офисом? А не с qt5.15?

Comment: Спросите у разрабов, если они скажут, что "а у нас всё работает для версии ____", значит проблема в  qt. Но я практически уверен, что либо html  в старом офисе не поддерживался, либо данный функционал реализовывался как-то по-другому. Вы пробовали в старой версии офиса вручную указать перенос строки в ячейке таблицы? Я, например, нет)